Want to make pen color change in QChart, QCandlestickSeries
This is my script to change color of the candle stick chart. All I want to do is when price is up, candle stick frame color should be green. Otherwise frame color is red. As you can see in the figure. Frame color is black and not red as I set in the code.
   # Add candlestick series
    candlestick_series = QCandlestickSeries()
    candlestick_series.setIncreasingColor(Qt.transparent)
    candlestick_series.setDecreasingColor(Qt.transparent)
    candlestick_series.setBodyOutlineVisible(True)  # Make bars hollow
    candlestick_series.pen=QColor.red

Read documentation but did't know what to set.

Aren't you just looking for candlestick_series.setIncreasingColor(Qt.green) etc.?
